# Custom chef provider not working

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I am trying to add a custom chef provider -- `Chef::Provider::Tarball` based on `Chef::Provider::Git`.

For some reason it does not want to work. I added:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/chef/provider/tarball.rb
```

And also added reference to `Chef::Provider::Tarball` in `/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/chef/provider/deploy.rb` and `/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/chef/providers.rb`:

```
require "chef/provider/tarball"
```

The error message I get is **FATAL: NameError: uninitialized constant Chef::Provider::Tarball**

Here is the full stack:

https://gist.github.com/7aa71a2088c5ec36d011

Any ideas what I could be missing?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? Please don't forget to mark an answer as correct! :)

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want to try and make a built in provider like that.  The proper way to handle it is to make a cookbook with an [LWRP](http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Lightweight+Resources+and+Providers+%28LWRP%29).  You can still use the LWRP in other cookbooks by depending on the cookbook containing the LWRP.  If you're sure you want a heavyweight provider rather than an LWRP you would likely want to build it into the Chef code itself (providers are under lib/chef/provider/) so it will be autoloaded and not use the require line.